# What won't this jquery count li elements on another page?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to count the number of li elements on a remote page, called file.xml. What am I doing wrong? Sorry for the easy question but I just can't figure this out.

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.get('/file.xml', function(data)
{
var allslides = $(data).find('li'),
var slidenumber = $allslides.length;
alert(slidenumber);
});
});
</script>
```

HTML (contents of file.xml):

```
    <body>
    <li><h2>Headline1</h2><span class="desctext">Description</span></li>
    <li><h2>Headline2</h2><span class="desctext">Description</span></li>
    <li><h2>Headline3</h2><span class="desctext">Description</span></li>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to specify that you are loading an XML file:

```
$.ajax({
    url      : '/file.xml',
    dataType : 'xml',
    success  : function (data) {
       var $allslides = $(data).find('li'),
           slidenumber = $allslides.length;
       alert(slidenumber);
    },
    error    : function () { /* don't forget to handle errors */ }
});
```

Also I noticed that your variable names don't really match-up, first you use `allslides` then you use `$allslides`. I normalized those variable names in my example code.

It also kind of looks like you're returning HTML rather than XML. Which will work, just change `dataType : 'xml'` to `dataType : 'html'` (or leave the option blank as `html` is the default). In a general sense it's a good idea to specify a content-type rather than letting jQuery guess on its own.

Documentation for `$.ajax()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: As this isn't XML, I'm not sure specifying `dataType: 'xml'` helps. But fixing the variable name sure does !